# DataRow 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been working with ASP.NET WebForms for a while and I've decided to try to convert some of my work into ASP.NET MVC.

Now, I can't figure out why my `DataRow` is `null` when there are results/rows.

**Here is the code and error**

[image: Here is the code and error]

```
string id= Session["role"].ToString() == "Admin" ? "0" : Session["emp_id"].ToString();

DataTable dt2 = getdata.accessAdmin(id);

DataRow[] dr = dt2.Select("default=0");

if (id != "0" && Session["emp_id"].ToString() != "0")
{
   <li>
     <a href="employee-dashboard"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i><span>Back </span></a>
   </li>
}

foreach (DataRow row in dr)
{
   if (row["url"].ToString().Length > 1)
     {
       <li>
       <a href="@row["url"]">
       <i class="@row["icon"]"></i><span>
              @row["name"]
        </span>
       </a>
      </li>
     }
}
```

my getdata.cs :

```
public static DataTable accessAdmin(string id)
{
    return dbhelper.getdata("Select a.user_id,b.* from nobel_userRight a left join nobel_route b on b.id=a.route_Id where b.system=2 and a.user_id=" + id + " order by seqs asc");
}
```

Comment: Include the actual code and not a screenshot. It's very difficult to tell whats going on based on a screenshot.

Comment: looks like `dr` is `null`. We need more code to see why that could be.

Comment: @JesseJohnson ,@Natrium please check my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: but why is it working in ASP.NET WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

The `Select("default=0");` doesn't look correct. Depending on the type of the `default` property, try changing the following line of code `DataRow[] dr = dt2.Select("default=0");` to one of the below:

**If the  property is an `int` then use**

```
DataRow[] dr = dt2.Where(r => r.default == 0);
```

**If the  property is a `bool` then use**

```
DataRow[] dr = dt2.Where(r => r.default == false);
```

Comment: i find see the .Where method

Comment: You may need to add `using System.Linq;` to your namespace imports list (likely at the top of the file).